# Is there a way to use a random number of randomly generated numbers as variables?

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to generate a random number of random numbers, then use them as variables to reference cells from a spreadsheet. Each of these lists of random numbers will reference a different range, each of which contains a list of 100 items, and I need to return the item associated with that numbered position in the list. Is there a way to do this? This is what I have so far, but I don't know where to go from here. Am I going about this all wrong, or what?

```
var physMutation = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
var mentMutation = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);

var mut1 = [];
var mut2 = [];

while(mut1.length < physMutation){
var r1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
if(mut1.indexOf(r1) === -1) mut1.push(r1);
}
console.log(mut1);
while(mut2.length < mentMutation){
var r2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
if(mut2.indexOf(r2) === -1) mut2.push(r2);
}
console.log(mut2);
```

Comment: Forget the code for a second; can you explain  more what you're trying to do. "generate a (`1`) **random number** of (`2`) **random numbers**, then use (`3`) **them** as variables... (`4`) **each of these** lists random numbers..." -- what do `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` represent? And what are the lower/upper bounds for the random numbers?

Comment: Okay, so I am trying to automate a character creation process which uses a 4 sided die to determine a number of total mutations of each type. Then, you roll a hundred sided die to determine which mutations the character has. There are two types of mutations, so they would be listed in two different arrays. I need a random number between 1 and 4 as the quantity of mutations, then the numbers between 1 and 100 for looking up the mutations so i can output them in a document.

Comment: I will edit the question to be more clear.

Comment: Can you share the sheet or share an example of what the data looks like?

Comment: @TheMaster Why do you feel this is a duplicate? The question marked as the duplicate looks like something different. They are both about random numbers but that can hardly be justification to mark something as a duplicate?

Comment: @IMTheNacho If it's not a duplicate, it's too broad and a open ended "how to" question or a unclear question. As to why, OP says *Each of these lists of random numbers will reference a different range, each of which contains a list of 100 items, and I need to return the item associated with that numbered position in the list. Is there a way to do this?* My answer in the duplicate does exactly that.  Creates a random array and uses it to return a item in the list/range. If it's not a duplicate, OP should explain why it's not so, by editing the question, so that it may be reopened.